# Large mysql database full text search

Tags: mysql, postgresql, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have a mysql database where one table has 500 mil records.
Table looks like this: **id|reference_id|data|other unimportant cols|**.
**data** type is text/varchar with a maximum of 500 chars (person names and companies).

I have to search through data to match against a keyword (firstname, lastname, part of a company name, etc.)

Mysql index on data column is not working, since i have to search even in the middle of the values.

Can mysql full-text search help me or i have to switch this table to elasticsearch for example? or maybe postgres ?

Search time has to be under 1 sec or lower on a medium server (4-8 cores, 16 gb ram, ssd)

Thanks

Comment: Why not try out full-text search and see how fast it is? It's not terribly complicated

Comment: Agreed. No one can tell you if it's going to be fast or not, only you can. So I suggest you try it out, measure the performance and then decide whether it's ok or not. In the latter case, you might need to proceed to step 2, i.e. moving/copying the data to be searched to Elasticsearch or any other respectable search engine.